# i want the image to be in 4 column but it falls in to other in bootstrap 5 and i triied img-responsive img-fluid but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frameworks

The 4 image which is defined : three of the images are in  1 row  but the 4th image keep falling in to another row
I tried using margin o mx-0 or px-0 but it only decreases its margin not its grid
Error Message: No error messages in the console.

Expected Behavior: I expect the 4 columns to be displayed side by side on larger screens and stacked on smaller screens.

Actual Behavior: The columns are not aligning properly. They are appearing stacked even on larger screens.

Steps Taken:

Checked the official Bootstrap documentation for proper usage.
Ensured that the Bootstrap CSS is properly linked.
Tried different column classes (col-md, col-lg, etc.) but the issue persists.
Browser/Device Information: Google Chrome on Windows 10.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" width="device=width-device" intial-scale="1" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1> Web Design is Awesome!!!</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="http://www.umich.edu/">University of Michigan</a>
      <a href="http://www.intro-webdesign.com/">Intro to Web Design</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section id="left" class="col-lg-3 col-lg-3">
        <h2>Why I am taking this class</h2>
        <ol>
          <li>It is required.</li>
          <li>I already know it, easy A!</li>
          <li>My mom wants a webpage.</li>
        </ol>
      </section>


      <section id="center" class="col-lg-8 col-lg-8">
        <h2>Why I am at University of Michigan</h2>
        <div class="myClass col-lg-12">
          <h3> Ann Arbor</h3>
          <p>There are many excellent reason to attend the <a href="umich.edu">University of Michigan</a>. The academics are top-notch, the students are exceptionally good-looking, and for about six weeks out of the year the weather is almost pleasant.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 d-none d-lg-block mt-1 ">

              <img class="col-lg-3 m-n5 px-0img-responsive" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="Football">

              <img class="col-lg-3 m-n4 px-0 img-responsive" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="Solar Car">

              <img class="col-lg-3 m-n5 px-0 img-responsive" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="campus">

              <img class="col-lg-3  m-n5 px-0 img-responsive" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="Football">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>Sample code for Responsive Design .<br/> Colleen van Lent</p>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Bootstrap Version: Bootstrap 5.3.0

Comment: I'm having trouble with your English. Please see if you can revise to be more clear. Also, why are you loading v5.0.2 here if you're actually using v5.3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `HTML` like this. I am assuming that you want your images to go side by side without gutter between them. Although there are some other issues as well with you `HTML` structure. But keeping in mind the question I am only referring here the solution.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block mt-1">
        <div class="row">
            <img class="col-lg-3 img-fluid" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="Football" />

            <img class="col-lg-3 img-fluid" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="Solar Car" />

            <img class="col-lg-3 img-fluid" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="campus" />

            <img class="col-lg-3 img-fluid" src="C:\Users\STIP User\Downloads\motivation\video 1\image\topg.jpg" alt="Football" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The real problem was that you are using `col-lg-3` inside `col-lg-12` instead of `row`.